# Start multiple batch Dataflow jobs from the same Cloud Function execution

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have created a custom template which reads from BigQuery using the `ReadFromBigQuery` I/O connector. I use it like this:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import StandardOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions

class CustomOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--query',
            help='Query to retrieve from BigQuery acting as data source.')
        parser.add_argument(
            '--bucket',
            default='mybucketname',
            help='Bucket name for staging, temp and schema files.')

options = PipelineOptions()
args = options.view_as(CustomOptions)
google_cloud_options = options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
google_cloud_options.project = 'myproject'
google_cloud_options.region = 'europe-west1'
google_cloud_options.staging_location = 'gs://{}/staging/'.format(args.bucket)
google_cloud_options.temp_location = 'gs://{}/tmp/'.format(args.bucket)
options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = 'DataflowRunner'
options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
options.view_as(SetupOptions).setup_file = './setup.py'


def run():
    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        (
            p
            | "Read from BigQuery" >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
                                          query=args.query,
                                          use_standard_sql=True,
                                          flatten_results=False)
            ...
        )
```

**setup.py**

```
import setuptools

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
    'apache-beam',
    'apache-beam[gcp]',
    'google-cloud-storage'
]

setuptools.setup(
    name='ProcessEmailMetrics',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='Workflow to process email metrics.',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True
)
```

Finally, this is how I make the Dataflow API call on my Cloud Function:

```
import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

credentials, _ = google.auth.default()
service = build('dataflow', 'v1b3', credentials=credentials, cache_discovery=False)

query = """
SELECT ...
"""

BODY = {
    'jobName': 'process-data',
    'gcsPath': 'gs://mybucket/templates/my_template',
    'parameters': {
      'query' : query
    }
}

req = service.projects().locations().templates().create(
    projectId='myproject',
    location='europe-west1',
    body=BODY
)

req.execute()
```

I start the job by making an API call launching the template on a Cloud Function listening to a Pub/Sub topic. If I publish only one message on the topic, the pipeline finish without any error. However, if I start multiple jobs from the same Cloud Function execution, I get two different errors.

The first one is about a missing file. The first two errors were of this type:

> HttpError accessing https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/my-bucket/o/tmp%2F6b2d2ba6-1%2Fbigquery-table-dump-000000000003.json?alt=media&generation=1628848711723613:
> response: <{'x-guploader-uploadid': 'ADPycdvNyinmSGSiYZPZw3GAJ4scmNLnGGsv5DUhowTZUYn_L6z9kMZ5b8oFWzPR2utFmTogffLijzmyfcJN_amILlmWQZa7aQ', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Fri, 13 Aug 2021 09:58:37 GMT', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin', 'expires': 'Fri, 13 Aug 2021 09:58:37 GMT', 'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0', 'content-length': '94', 'server': 'UploadServer', 'status': '404'}>, content <No such object: my-bucket/tmp/6b2d2ba6-1/bigquery-table-dump-000000000003.json>

The second one is an index error out of range, again when reading the avro files generated on `ReadFromBigQuery`. The next three errors were of this type:

> 2021-08-13 12:03:48.656 CESTError message from worker: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 651, in do_work work_executor.execute() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 179, in execute op.start() File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 38, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 39, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 44, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 48, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/concat_source.py", line 84, in read for record in self._source_bundles[source_ix].source.read( IndexError: list index out of range

After this five errors happened, my pipeline failed and stopped.

It seems like the `ReadFromBigQuery` connector is looking for a temporal file containing some BigQuery rows which actually does not exist, or has been messed up.

As I have said, if I start only one Dataflow job it finishes without any error, so I have two hypothesis.

1. It may be related with my Cloud Function. When two messages are published too close on time, the function does not have time to go to sleep, and maybe the files paths are messed that way.

   - Can this problem be produced by the `cache_discovery=False` option when creating the `build` Dataflow service?
2. Maybe, it is due to how my template is coded:

   - May the `options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True` option be the key of the problem?
   - May I need to provide somehow a specific temporal dataset for each job execution when reading from / writing to BigQuery?
   - A different temporal location on `google_cloud_options.temp_location = 'gs://{}/tmp/'.format(args.bucket)` for each job execution?

I need to be able to start several Dataflow jobs on the same Cloud Function execution, so the actual behaviour does not fit my project needs.

Here you are one of my failed job's ID: `2021-08-13_02_54_10-11165491620802897150`.

Any idea how to fix this?

**UPDATE:**

Versions

```
python: 3.7.3 (on Cloud Shell)
beam: 2.31.0 (on Cloud Shell)
beam: undefined (on setup.py)
```

Comment: looking at this in detail... what beam version are you using?

Comment: @Pablo I updated the question with the different versions. I create the template through Cloud Shell running `python3 -m myfile --template_location gs://mybucket/templates/mytemplate`. On Cloud Shell I installed apache-beam version 2.31.0, and I use python 3.7.3. When installing beam in the workers through `setup.py`, I did not declare any specific version, and I installed both `apache-beam` and `apache-beam[gcp]`. Thanks for your time reading this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that both pipelines are performing a Bigquery export into the same temporary directory, and they're steppign on each other's toes. You can provide a different directory for each one, like so:

Can you try providing separate GCS locations to your ReadFromBigQuery transforms? You'd do something like this:

```py
class CustomOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        ...
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--export_location',
            help='GCS location to perform Bigquery export')
        ...
```

And in your pipeline you would pass this export location separately:

```py
def run():
    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        (
            p
            | "Read from BigQuery" >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
                                          query=args.query,
                                          use_standard_sql=True,
                                          flatten_results=False,
                                          gcs_location=options.export_location)
            ...
        )
```

Finally, you autogenerate a new one every time you start a pipeline:

```js
BODY = {
    'jobName': 'process-data',
    'gcsPath': 'gs://mybucket/templates/my_template',
    'parameters': {
      'query' : query,
      'export_location': 'gs://mybucket/templates/my_template/tmp/' + str(uuid.uuid4())
    }
}

req = service.projects().locations().templates().create(
    projectId='myproject',
    location='europe-west1',
    body=BODY
)

req.execute()
```

Comment: I followed your advise and after applying the changes I was able to start several jobs simultaneously without experiencing any error. I also have a "WriteToBigQuery" connector on my pipeline, and as the `custom_gcs_temp_location` parameter does not accept a `ValueProvider`, I did not modify that PTransform. I wonder why the problem was only on reading and not also on writting to BigQuery. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: right! So the BQ Read does the following: (BQ export into Dir -> read all files in dir) -- the BQ Write does the following: (write to files -> BQ import *concrete list of files*) - so two writes don't step on each other's toes : )

Comment: Thanks for the explanación, now everything is more clear for me!